# Create Hotels search Form in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, form

I am working on sharepoint 2013 and I want to create a simple form where users can search for company hotels offers.

I have a list with all hotel offers (names, dates, prices, locations...) and users need to fill form (where are they traveling, dates, persons, ...) and then a list of all rooms based on entered values is diplayed.
and then user click on the hotel and send a request to other department.

I am not aware if this possible in sharepoint 2013.

I can use Nintex Forms and workflows. or if there is any other available solution please let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

from your question , i understand that the below is one of the requirement.

//I am working on sharepoint 2013 and I want to create a simple form where users can search for company hotels offers.//

This can be possible with Search service Application.

Enterprise search will help you achieve the same.

for your requirement , you can create a solution based on the below details.

[Step-by-Step: Provisioning the Search Service Application](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2009/11/23/step-by-step-provisioning-the-search-service-application/)

[Create and configure a Search service application in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/gg502597.aspx)

[Keyword Query Language (KQL) syntax reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[How to change the way search results are displayed in SharePoint Server 2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/08/27/how-to-change-the-way-search-results-are-displayed-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)

[Overview of search in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj219738.aspx)

[Search reference articles from MSDN](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/?m=20139)

Please upvote and mark it as answer if this really helps.

Comment: The user will select:(city, from and to dates, how many adults, if there is children) after clicking search. the result will appear in neat way (if possible like showing the hotel name, pic, prices, ...) and user select the item s/he find suitable. after that, a request with data selected is sent to related department to proceed. I will look for Search service Application.

Comment: For that you need to customise search query using Search query builder tool or you can write CSOM/JSOM based solution to get the user queries and pass it on with KQL. I will edit my answer to include it, this is suggestion you can try it out once you understand how keyword query functions and how you going to customise search queries.